# Display -1st level of active menu item

Tags: routes, panels, blocks

I am using the [menu block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) with panels to add a sidebar menu to each page. It works great, except that where the options for "Starting level will be" are "active menu item" and "children of active menu item". I need one level up, that is, parent of active menu item and that item's siblings. I want to always show one level up, the current level, and the children of the current item.

Is there a way to do this with menu block? Or any other contrib module? Or should I write this and submit a patch to menu block?